# Flutter Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s) (value): Must not be null

Tags: flutter, dart

this method was working fine if i provide a null value it will not throw error, but after updating to flutter 2.1 now it throws an exception if i provide null value whats the best solution for this please

```
  /// Method that saves the user lang in shared preferences
  static Future<dynamic> setLanguage (value) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.setString(_language, value);
  }
```

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception:
> Invalid argument(s) (value): Must not be null
>
> E/flutter (22502): #0      ArgumentError.checkNotNull
> (dart:core/errors.dart:185:27) E/flutter (22502): #1
> SharedPreferences._setValue
> (package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart:147:19) E/flutter
> (22502): #2      SharedPreferences.setString
> (package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart:133:7)

Comment: The updated package must be having a null check, so before setting the `value`, just check if it is null or not and only set if it is not null

Comment: is this something new related to dart null safety? and thanks for the answer it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value then save it:

```
 static Future<dynamic> setLanguage (value) async {
    if (value != null){
      final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      return prefs.setString(_language, value);
    }
   return null;
 }
```

Comment: is this something new related to dart null safety? in drat flutter, and thanks for the answer it works now

Comment: The package has migrated to null safety and it checks for the null value.